# How to join thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How to join thread in this code? Like thread1.join , thread2.join how to do this in this code.  please help me to understand how to join thread in this code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Customer c=new Customer();
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
        {



        new Thread(){  

        public void run(){c.player1("player1");}  
        }.start();


        new Thread(){   
        public void run(){c.player2("player2");}  
        }.start(); 


        new Thread(){   
            public void run(){c.player3("player3");}  
            }.start(); 


        new Thread(){   
            public void run(){c.player4("player4");}  
            }.start(); 
    }



    }

}
```

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: language -  java

Comment: You need to store the threads as a reference, otherwise they'll never join back to the main thread like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the references of threads you created and then use those references to call join().

```
   public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Customer c = new Customer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            Thread thread1 = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    c.player1("player1");
                }
            };

            Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    c.player2("player2");
                }
            };
            thread2.start();

            Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    c.player3("player3");
                }
            };
            thread3.start();

            Thread thread4 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    c.player4("player4");
                }
            };

            thread4.start();
            try {
                thread1.join();
                thread2.join();
                thread3.join();
                thread4.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }

}

class Customer {

    public void player1(String string) {
    }

    public void player3(String string) {
    }

    public void player2(String string) {
    }

    public void player4(String string) {
    }

}
```